# meaning of DO in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, questions, do-support

What is the meaning of **does** in this sentence?

> Whose exhibition **does** “Stars At Dusk” painting belong to?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

It got no meaning. It's an **auxiliary verb** used to construct the question in English.
The main verb in your phrase is **belong**.

According to the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/auxiliary-verbs)

> **Auxiliary verbs** are so called because they help to form the various
>   tenses, moods, and voices of other verbs. The principal ones are be,
>   **do**, and have.

You can find additional information about constructing wh- questions in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/questions-and-negative-sentences/questions-wh-questions).

Answer (score 1):

Does is the 'helping verb'.
It helps to construct the sentence. We often use the verb 'to do' to help construct question sentences.
Other examples:

Who do you know in America?
Main verb: know
Helping  verb: do

Whose exhibition does 'The Stars at Dusk' painting belong to?
Main verb: belong
Helping verb: does

The helping verb and subject (I, you, we) must agree!
Do - I, You, We, They
Does - He, She, It. *The dog* or in this case *The Stars At Dusk*